# Is the surface in $\mathbb{A}^3$ rational?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

Consider the surface
$$
(u_1^6 + 1)w^3 = (u_2^6 + 1) \subset \mathbb{A}^3
$$
over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p \neq 2,3$. Is it rational, i.e., is there its proper parametrization by two independent variables ?

Comment: $(u_1,u_2,w)$ is the triple of coordinates?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: Consider the "homogenized" surface in $\mathbb{P}^3 \times \mathbb{P}^1$, with coordinates $([u_0,u_1,u_2],[v,w])$ given by the equation $(u_1^6+u_0^6)w^3-(u_2^6+u_0^6)v^3$.  By direct computation, this is a smooth hypersurface of bidegree $(6,3)$.  By adjunction, the canonical divisor class of this hypersurface is the restriction of a divisor class of bidegree $(3,1)$, which is ample.  Thus, this smooth surface is of general type: it is *not* unirational.

Comment: I just redid the computation.  There are precisely two singular points at $([0,1,0],[1,0])$ and at $([0,0,1],[0,1])$.  The exceptional divisor of each blowing up of each is a smooth curve of genus $10$ . . .

Comment: Thank you for the help.